# AES encryption under contiki on CC2650

Tags: aes, contiki

I am currently trying to add AES encryption to an existing beacon-demo that uses the TI cc2650 sensortag. I am using the AES API provided by contiki under core/lib. 
My main looks like this:

```
static const uint8_t AES_key[16] = { 0xC0 , 0xC1 , 0xC2 , 0xC3 ,
                                 0xC4 , 0xC5 , 0xC6 , 0xC7 ,
                                 0xC8 , 0xC9 , 0xCA , 0xCB ,
                                 0xCC , 0xCD , 0xCE , 0xCF };// AES Key

static uint8_t plain_text[16] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
14, 15, 16}; // Plain-text to be encrypted.
const struct aes_128_driver AES_128;
.
.
.
printf("Plain_Text: %d \r\n", plain_text);
AES_128.set_key(AES_key);
AES_128.encrypt(plain_text);
printf("Encrypted_Text: %p\r\n", plain_text);
```

Unfortunately when I run the code the plain text is unchangeable. Using some extra prints, I realize that the encrypt function is working but the output is still unchangeable. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Please note that I already added the following line to my conf file:

```
#define AES_128_CONF aes_128_driver
```

Comment: Is all this code inside in a function?

Comment: No, this is just a small part of a long functioning code that reads sensor data and sends it over a (IEEE 802.15.4) channel.

Comment: What I'm asking about is if the code block you posted is inside a function or in a file scope? The first part before the "..." in particular?

Comment: I see, so the first lines are written right under the "#define" section and the second part is called inside of a PROCESS_THREAD that is calling various other static voids. Do you think that I should put my code in such a static void and call it in the PROCESS_THREAD?

Comment: That's fine - I was wondering if `const struct aes_128_driver AES_128` could be a local variable that's shadowing the global one. You don't need it in any case. I've been running AES on CC2650 without problems, but can't see the issue with your code.

Comment: Can you maybe point me to a simple AES example that uses the contiki AES API other than the CCM example (https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/lib/ccm-star.c)

Comment: Sorry, our code is private at the moment. But your code was working for me (encrypted the string to something), so there must be some problem in your setup.

Comment: Well I will look more into it. Thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as @kfx pointed out in the comments `const struct aes_128_driver AES_128` was shadowing the global variable.